# C - Problem with message passing between threads using queues

Tags: c, pthreads, message-queue

I'm trying to pass messages between 2 threads using a queue, but I haven't gotten any results so far. When I print the contents of the message after it's received and before it's sent, it only seems to keep its value within the tread. I need to implement it with 1 server thread and multiple client threads, but for now I'm only using 1 of each. Here's my code

```
struct msg                                //struct for client requests to server
{
        long mtype;
        int numResources;           //number of resources to be requested
        int ID;                     //ID associated with client thread
};                                         

int c1PID;                              //process ID variable for client thread 1
int serverPID;

key_t key1;
key_t keyS;

int msqid1;
int msqidS;

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
        key1 = ftok(".", '1');      //queue for client thread 1 to receive msgs from server
        msqid1 = msgget(key1, 666 | IPC_CREAT);

        keyS = ftok(".", 's');                          //general queue for server
        msqidS = msgget(keyS, 666 | IPC_CREAT);

        pthread_t threads[2];              //create an array of pthreads

        if ((serverPID = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, server, NULL)) != 0)
        {
                perror("server thread");
                exit(1);
        }

        if ((c1PID = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, client, NULL)) != 0)
        {
                perror("client thread");
                exit(1);
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *server()
{                                  
        struct msg request;
        size_t size = sizeof(struct msg) - offsetof(struct msg, numResources);

        while (1)
        {

                msgrcv(msqidS, &request, size, 2, 0);

                printf("received: numResources requested = %d\n", request.numResources);

                request.numResources = 9001;

                printf("sending: numResources requested = %d\n", request.numResources);

                msgsnd(msqid1, &request, size, 0);

                sleep(1);
        }
}

void *client()
{
        struct msg request;
        size_t size;
        request.numResources = 0;
        size = sizeof(struct msg) - offsetof(struct msg, numResources);

        msgsnd(msqidS, &request, size, 0);

        while(1)
        {
                msgrcv(msqid1, &request, size, 2, 0);

                printf("received: numResources requested = %d\n", request.numResources);

                request.numResources += 1;//(int)(ceil((double)(rand()%2)) + 1);

                printf("sending: numResources requested = %d\n", request.numResources);

                msgsnd(msqidS, &request, size, 0);

                sleep(1);
}
```

I took out a lot of my print statements, but it looks something like this:

```
Server thread: 
received: numResources = 9001;
sending: numResources = 9001;

client thread:
received: numResources = 1;
sending: numResources = 2;

Server thread: 
received: numResources = 9001;
sending: numResources = 9001;

client thread:
received: numResources = 2;
sending: numResources = 3;
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a client server program which will be on two separate machines or are you just going to have two threads that talk to each other?

Comment: They're just talking to each other on the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
The sizeof(struct msg) - offsetof(struct msg, numResources); should be ok.

But, your `mtype` needs to be, as per the [docs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgsnd.html), a positive integer. Initialize it to 2, as your calls to msgrecv says to receive only message type 2.

Add error checking to all the msgsnd/msgrecv calls , so you're sure you're not silently getting errors.

Add error checking to your ftok and msgget calls.

Comment: I originally offset it by numResources because a queue tutorial I was following said to offset by the data member immediately after mtype. I tried changing it to ID and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Right now I'm passing in offsetof(struct msg, ID) as the size paramater and still no luck : / I'll try adding error messages to the sending/receiving

Comment: Hmmm, I put in error catching (if sending/receiving functions == -1, print error and exit) and it returned "Invalid argument". But I followed my tutorial guide as closely as possible, I'm not sure what arguments aren't correct.

Comment: " EINVAL Invalid msqid value, or nonpositive mtype value, or invalid msgsz value (less than 0 or greater than the system value MSGMAX).
" . You need to initialize `mtype` ,as mentioned in the answer now.

Comment: I actually initialized mtype while I was reading up more on msgsend/rcv while waiting for responses, but that hasn't changed anything. I'm going to add error checking for the queue creation to double check that.

Comment: Hmmm, I set an error catch for the msqid creation (if ==-1, print error statement and exit) and it told me "Permission denied". But then I added error catching for key creation (if key == -1, print error, exit) and now it appears to be working?
EDIT: I just ran it twice in a row after adding the error catching. The first time it gave me results I would expect if it were working. The second time I ran it, it printed results as if it had passed a message once, but then went back to not working (numResources only being updated within each thread separately). I'll post results as a answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have set nonsense permissions on your message queues.  In these lines, you have used a decimal constant `666` where you should have used an octal constant `0666`:

```
    msqid1 = msgget(key1, 666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msqid1 = msgget(key1, 666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

This means that you've created the queues with octal permissions `01232`, which doesn't include read permission - so your subsequent `msgget()` calls are all now failing with `EPERM` (which you'll see if you check those calls for errors).

You will have to remove your message queues and allow your program to re-create them with the correct permissions.  You need to use the `msqid` for the queue with the `IPC_RMID` command to `msgctl()` to do this, as in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <msqid> [<msgqid> ...]\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        while (*++argv)
        {
                int msqid = atoi(*argv);

                printf("Removing msqid %d\n", msqid);
                if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) != 0) {
                        perror("msgctl");
                        return 2;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Due to the awful design of SYS V message queues, you can't get the `msqid` values from `msgget()` anymore, because `msgget()` fails.  To get the `msqid` values to remove, look in the file `/proc/sysvipc/msg`.

**PS:**

I highly recommend using POSIX message queues instead (`mq_open()`, `mq_send()`, `mq_receive()` etc.).  The interface is significantly improved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it printed on the run that appeared to work.

```
program starting
Msg sent from client

*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 0
sending: numResources requested = 1
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 1
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.


*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9002
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 9002
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.


*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9002
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 9002
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.


*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9002
Msg sent from client
```

And immediately after....

```
program starting
Msg sent from client

*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9002
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 0
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.


*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9002
sending: numResources requested = 9003
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.


*****In client thread*****
Msg received by client
received: numResources requested = 9003
sending: numResources requested = 9004
Msg sent from client


*****In server thread*****
Msg received by server
received: numResources requested = 9001
sending: numResources requested = 9001
Msg sent from server.
```

These were run 1 after the other with no changes made to the code in between.

Comment: I ran it again, and it gave me really odd numbers the first few loops, but then settled back on the results from the first iteration where it appeared to be working. No idea....
EDIT: Ran it a 4th time and it's giving me the results of the second run. I see a pattern...