# C - Thread result in main

Tags: c, multithreading, return

I'm studying C but my book offers really few resources. I'd like to know if it's possible and it's useful to use the thread to elaborate something and then pass the result to the main. In case, I'd like to know how to pass informations from a thread to the main (Something like method return in java). The only solution is to use a global variable?
Here's a little example to explain what I'd like to do. Is this possible/useful?

main:

```
int i = 1;
pthread_create(tid,NULL,functionTH,NULL);
int z = //getResultFromThread
```

thread "function":

```
void * functionTH(){
    int z = 2;
    //return value 2 to the main and assign it to k in the main.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the prototype of [pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html).

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
       const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
       void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

Your thread (`start_routine`) is a function that returns a `void *`.  So your code is wrong since your thread function returns nothing.  As you can guess, you return a value to your main thread by returning a pointer.

You can wait for the thread to complete to read this value by calling [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html).  The value you return from the thread is passed via the `value_ptr` arg.

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread
>   has already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join()
>   call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to
>   pthread_exit() by the terminating thread shall be made available in
>   the location referenced by value_ptr.

Of course, you don't have to use this mechanism.  Global variables can work just fine, but you do have to synchronize access to the variable or you'll end up with a race condition.

Comment: mm but value_ptr should be a void both in pthread_join and pthread_exit, so how can I pass a INT throught it?

Comment: You can cast `(void *)` the pointer of for example `struct` that will contain your `i` and `k`.

Comment: So, something like this should work? `void * functionTH(){
 pthread_exit((void*)22);
}`
main: `pthread_join(tid,(void*)&k); printf("%d",k);`

Comment: @daimpa:  Your edit changed your thread function from `void functionTH(void * i)`, which was wrong, to `void * functionTH()`, which is still wrong.  Try `void *functionTH(void *arg)`.  And yes, something like that would work, but you don't have to call `pthread_exit`.  Just `return (void *)22;`.  The pthread library takes care of getting it to the main thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751017/pthread-why-people-bother-using-pthread-exit.

Comment: @daimpa:  And you might be able to imagine a situation where you could define all the data you want to pass or return in a `struct`, and then allocate the struct with `malloc`, pass a pointer to it either in our out of your thread, and then have the recipient of that data `free` that data when done with it.  That's how you get a lot of data in or out of your thread.  But often an integer is all you need, and casting it to a pointer `(void *)22` is sufficient.

Comment: @indiv thanks for the reply. Now it doesn't compile, as it says: "undefined reference to "phtread_join"" "undefined reference to "phtread_create""

Comment: @daimpa:  ... did you link with the pthread library with `-lpthread`?  E.g., `gcc -o program program.c ‑lpthread`

Comment: @indiv I'm compiling this through geany. Is this wrong?

Comment: @daimpa:  No, that's not wrong.  I really cannot provide tech support for a specific IDE that I've never used, so if you can't figure out where to add `-lpthread`, maybe ask a new question.

Comment: @indiv thank you so much for your help, I've compiled it through terminal and it worked! I'll open a new question for geany. Thanks again!

Comment: @indiv: I've a new problem. It worked because I returned an integer. But if I return (void*)usr where usr is a local variable of the thread, it fails "warning: function returns address of local variable"

Answer (score 1):

Memory is shared between threads, thus it's easy to just pass pointers around using [queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) (use one queue per thread). Also, Remember to use [mutex locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and other [concurrency control techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Here's another S.O post which shows how to implement [message passing between threads using queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180735/c-problem-with-message-passing-between-threads-using-queues).

This article titled, "[Queues, Mutexes, Semaphores..](http://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html)," does a great job in explaining all the caveats you have to consider with race-conditions and critical sections when you're building a multi-threaded program in C.

If you're interested in learning about performance, Bartosz Milewski's article titled, "[Beyond Locks and Messages: The Future of Concurrent Programming](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2010/08/02/beyond-locks-and-messages-the-future-of-concurrent-programming/)," does a great job of juxtaposing shared memory and message passing and gives great insight into the advantages of transactional memory and the disadvantages of classical locks.

Please let me know if you have any questions!